# What exactly happens in the JVM when invoking an object's instance method?

Tags: java, methods, jvm

I think I have finally found out how to word, what is giving me so much trouble in understanding: how the virtual machine can access a classes methods and use it only on a given instance (object) with the catch that the virtual machine is only being given the reference/pointer variable.

This was compounded by the fact that most visualizations of the methods interacting with the stack/heap (that is shown to most beginner Java programmers) don’t quite go deep enough into the depth I am in looking for.

I have done a lot of research, and I want to say a good summary of what I learned, and I am asking if you could please correct me where I am wrong (or elaborate further if you think there is more that could be said)! Note that I am using this portion of an article I found (I am using it more as a visual reference, I understand some of the text in the article does not pertain to the question), so please take a look at it before reading onward:

[image]

So let’s say I have a reference/pointer variable `foo1` that is of type `Foo`(was created using a constructor called `Foo`). `foo1` is stored on the stack, but the object it points to is stored on the heap (the `Foo` object having an instance variable `int size;`).

So I understand how `foo1.size` would give the integer value of `size` because the value of `foo1` is dereferenced to get the value field of `size` (the reference/pointer variable has a direct address where the `size` field is stored on the heap in the object).

But when `foo1.bar()` is ran, what exactly does its bytecode translate to? And how is this method call performed at runtime (would it be correct to say the value of `foo1` is being dereferenced to get method `bar()`)?

Does it relate correctly to the diagram in the image above (all in the JVM: does it go from the reference/pointer variable `foo1` on the stack to the heap which is actually a pointer to another pointer (which points to the bytecode of all the class data) `full class data` (in a `method table` which is just an array of pointers to the data for each instance method that can be invoked on objects of that class) in the method area which then itself has "pointer variables" to the actual bytecode `method data`)?

I apologize for how long-winded this post is, but I want to be extremely specific since I have had major trouble the past week trying to word my question properly. I know I sound sceptical of the article I am referencing, but it seems there is a lot of junk visualizations out there and I want to be sure that I’m continuing my Java programming correctly, and not on incorrect notions.

Comment: you're probably better off going through a technical reference (or maybe a blog article summarizing one) than asking this sort of question here.  it's hard work to write a good explanation of something this complicated here.  the answer depends a lot on how abstractly you're thinking, e.g. JIT compilation could result in the operation being inlined, while a naive interpreter would need to do more lookups

Comment: @Holger **PART 1: ** Thank you for the reply Holger! In previous versions of this question I went more in depth on not just what I currently know, but what I was asking (which problematically split into multiple questions), but due to the question being more general in nature it kepted being closed for not being focused enough. So I thought asking different questions bit by bit and stripping it down to the bare minimum would help. I totally understand your pedal analogy, but it does not mean I am not willing to learn it! I still have the drive of curoisty to find out! I have done a lot of

Comment: @Holger **PART 2:** digging around to try, and get an answer to my overall question not just the "dot-notation invoking" question. But it is hard to find someone willing to write an article going into the meat and potatos of it all! I wont lie the journey has led me to understanding and learning a lot, like understanding bytecode, and source codes journey from getting compiled into bytecode -> then the JIT Compiler turning the bytecode into machine code! I am still pretty new to Stack overflow as a hole and now I realize it is probably not the place to be asking these types of questions

Comment: @Holger **PART 3:** If you have any tips on where you think I should look next please let me know!

Comment: @SamMason Thank you very much for the response! Youre right! I have realized that this isn't quite the place for these longer form questions, more specific questions on one idea. Problem is I have been running into this problem with articles as well, not digging into the meat and potatos, or not really answering what I exactly had in mind (instead being more surface level, and following the "If I cant see it, then I dont need to worry about it" type of way). I will continue my rabbit hole search though!

Comment: @SamMason Just to add! I think im having a hard time figuring out what level of abstraction I am thinking at!

Comment: [The Java® Virtual Machine Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/index.html) is *the* place to find all the details about Java bytecode and the (formal) behavior it can expect from a JVM. For the widespread implementation, HotSpot, there’s [this overview](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/docs/RuntimeOverview.html) and [the OpenJDK wiki](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot), the latter containing lots of details how certain things have been implemented or optimized. It’s also worth knowing [vtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table).

Comment: As revised, I think this question is answerable by discussing what the line translates to in bytecode (pretty simple), and then how the method call is performed at runtime (more complex, but fits within the scope of an answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ordinary instance method invocations get compiled to `invokevirtual` instructions.

This has been described in [JVMS, §3.7. Invoking Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/jvms-3.html#jvms-3.7):

> The normal method invocation for a instance method dispatches on the run-time type of the object. (They are virtual, in C++ terms.) Such an invocation is implemented using the *invokevirtual* instruction, which takes as its argument an index to a run-time constant pool entry giving the internal form of the binary name of the class type of the object, the name of the method to invoke, and that method's descriptor ([§4.3.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.3.3)). To invoke the `addTwo` method, defined earlier as an instance method, we might write:
>
> ```java
> int add12and13() {
>     return addTwo(12, 13);
> }
> ```
>
> This compiles to:
>
> ```
> Method int add12and13()
> 0   aload_0             // Push local variable 0 (this)
> 1   bipush 12           // Push int constant 12
> 3   bipush 13           // Push int constant 13
> 5   invokevirtual #4    // Method Example.addtwo(II)I
> 8   ireturn             // Return int on top of operand stack;
>                         // it is the int result of addTwo()
> ```
>
> The invocation is set up by first pushing a `reference` to the current instance, `this`, on to the operand stack. The method invocation's arguments, `int` values `12` and `13`, are then pushed. When the frame for the `addTwo` method is created, the arguments passed to the method become the initial values of the new frame's local variables. That is, the `reference` for `this` and the two arguments, pushed onto the operand stack by the invoker, will become the initial values of local variables `0`, `1`, and `2` of the invoked method.

---

It’s up to the particular JVM implementation, how to perform the invocation at runtime, but using a [vtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) is very common. This basically matches the graphic in your question. The reference to the receiver object, which will become the `this` reference for the invoked method, is used to retrieve a method table.

In the HotSpot JVM, the metadata structure is called `Klass` (actually a common name, even across different implementations). See [“Object header layout” on the OpenJDK Wiki](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/CompressedOops#CompressedOops-Objectheaderlayout):

> An object header consists of a native-sized mark word, a klass word, a 32-bit length word (if the object is an array), a 32-bit gap (if required by alignment rules), and then zero or more instance fields, array elements, or metadata fields. (Interesting Trivia: Klass metaobjects contain a C++ vtable immediately after the klass word.)

When resolving a symbolic reference to a method, its corresponding index in the table will be identified and remembered for subsequent invocations, as it never changes. Then, the entry of the actual object’s class can be used for the invocation. Subclasses will have the entries of the superclass, new methods appended to the end, with the entries of overridden methods replaced.

---

This is the simple, unoptimized scenario. Most runtime optimizations work better when methods are inlined, to have the context of caller and callee in one piece of code to transform. Therefore, the HotSpot JVM will attempt inlining even for *invokevirtual* instructions to potentially overridable methods. As [the wiki says](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/PerformanceTechniques#PerformanceTechniques-Methods):

> - Virtual (and interface) invocations are often demoted to "special" invocations, if the class hierarchy permits it. A dependency is registered in case further class loading spoils things.
> - Virtual (and interface) invocations with a lopsided type profile are compiled with an optimistic check in favor of the historically common type (or two types).
> - Depending on the profile, a failure of the optimistic check will either deoptimize or run through a (slow) vtable/itable call.
> - On the fast path of an optimistically typed call, inlining is common. The best case is a de facto monomorphic call which is inlined. Such calls, if back-to-back, will perform the receiver type check only once.

This aggressive or optimistic inlining will sometime require [Deoptimization](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/PerformanceTechniques#PerformanceTechniques-Deoptimization) but will usually yield an overall higher performance.

Comment: **PART 1:** I just had a breakthrough moment! First off THANK YOU! Thank you very very much, I finally can say I feel confident that I understand, and there are no loose ends. Second, I moved all the code over from VSCode to Eclipse so I could actually follow step by step through my own code and look at and examine the `bytecode`. It took me so long to reply because inbetween my classes all yesterday I made this diagram going through the `bytecode` of my constructor method, and instance method `addLast(T newElement)` being used ---> https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqnja.png

Comment: **PART 2:** If you could look through it and double check everything I made checks out, that would mean a ton to me! I do have one last question though: Can you look at this exact area and make sure this spot checks out correctly completely(this was the main problem area I was having trouble understanding) --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgoFx.png . And lastly I just want to say I learned so much not just about my question but the JVM through this endevour! Holger multiple times I saw your replies and answers to questions on years old questions (while I was making my diagram). Youre a huge help!

Comment: Also really quick I want to add, there are grey/black rectangles all over the diagrams and that is because I used my name in the code, so I was just covering it up!

Comment: I don’t know what exact question you have about the diagram. It looks correct, as far as I can recognize (it’s not the best diagram type for operations over time).

Comment: **Part 1:** Basically what I am asking is: Is the way that—inside the `addLast()` method frame—the instance method knows to use the head node from the `MyLinkedList myList1` and not say some other `MyLinkedList myList2` because it uses the bytecode instruction `getfield` which pops and uses the reference address stored in `MLLAD` (`MyLinkedList`) (that was the reference address to the object on the heap coming from the `invokevirtual` step in the `main()` frame)  off the Operand Stack, then uses this address to go into the heap and grab the specific head node only "belonging" to `myList1` and

Comment: `getfield` pops the object reference to use from the operand stack, which is the result of the preceding `aload_0` instruction, which is the `this` instance. Because for non-`static` methods, variable `0` gets preinitialized with `this` on method entry. Which is the reference provided to the `invokevirtual` instruction by the caller (would work the same for `invokeinterface` and `invokespecial`).

Comment: **Part 2:** Okay so just to make sure i get this right. The reason why getfield only has to specify `getfield MyLinkedList.head` and not something like say (what I previously and wrongfully thought was) `getfield MyLinkedList[some identifier unique only to myList1].head` is because in this current frame `MyLinkedList`( `MLLAD` in the diagram) only has the address pointing to the object on the heap from `myList1`. On the flip side, if `invokevirtual` was called because in the `main()` frame I did `myList2.addLast()` (instead of `myList1.addLast()`) the object reference `MLLAD` on the

Comment: operand stack (in the new frame `addLast()`), is a pointer to a different object on the heap (`myList2`) despite having the same name `MLLAD` (`MyLinkedList`). I just realized what was tripping me up is, it using the `MLLAD` for both `myList1` and `myList2` and no identifier to differentiate between the two. But now I realize its because `MLLAD` is initialized to point to different addresses.

Comment: It would be like someone saying "howcome you are using `foo` as a variable name in two different java projects?" ahaha, I dont know how I didn't see that, maybe because it was in bytecode I was thinking there would be more unique identifiers. When that does not make sense!

Comment: In source code, that identifier is always “`this`”…